# Mongodb to Mongodb GridFS

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I'm new to mongodb. I wanted to know if I initially code my app using mongodb and later I want to switch to mongodb gridfs, will the switching (of a filled large database) be possible.

So, if I am using mongo db initially and after some time of running the app the database documents exceed the size of 16Mb, I guess I will have to switch to gridfs. I want to know how easy or difficult will it be to switch to gridfs and whether that will be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps some context to your question rather than a single sentence might explain what you want

Comment: Trying to help you here. You really need to do a lot more that what you have. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hope the question is clear now!

Comment: you need to write different code for GrdFS if using any native driver for coding.

Comment: Hey dev, thanks a lot for your comment. Is there a problem in converting from normal mongo db into gridfs. I mean the data in the database (not the coding part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is used to store large files. It internally divides data in chunks(By default 255 KB). Let me give you an example of saving a pdf file in MongoDB using both ways. I am assuming the size of pdf as 10 MB so that we can see both normal way and GridFS way.

- Normal Way:

  Say you want to store it in `normal_book` collection in `testDB` database. So, whole pdf is stored in this collection and when you want to fetch it using `db.normal_book.find()`, whole pdf will be fetched in memory.
- GridFS way:

  In GridFS, we have two collections, one is for storing data and other is for storing its metadata. It will store data in `fs.chunks` collection and metadata in `fs.files`collection. Now, the beauty of GridFS is that you can find the whole file at once or you can find chunks individually.

> Now coming to your question, there is no direct way or property to
>   tell `MongoDB` that now I want to switch to `GridFS`. You need to
>   **reinsert** data in GridFS using  [mongofiles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongofiles/#bin.mongofiles) command-line tool or
>   using MongoDB's [drivers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/drivers/).

Comment: @Vijay try to explore the documentation to grasp more about it. you can ask if you need any clarification or code example.

Comment: Thanks dev, appreciate your help!